# Blog editing problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, counter

I am a novice blogger and i wanted to create a counter on my blog which will increase value when the button is click so far after searching for long on web i came up with this result

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#AddButton').click( function() {
                var counter = $('#TextBox').val();
                counter++ ;
                $('#TextBox').val(counter);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

now what i need is that people may click on the button twice so i want to make sure a person clicks only once from a browser and that value should be saved at least on the text box even for other people, please help me...

Comment: So this is basically a "like" box. Are you saving the results in a database? Because if not you have a long way to go before you have to worry about the button only being pressed once.

Comment: how to save the results i a database cuz i am using blog and dont know how to setup a database for a blog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use one option to prevent multiple click.

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#AddButton').one( "click", function() {
                var counter = $('#TextBox').val();
                counter++ ;
                $('#TextBox').val(counter);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: where should i keep it